# Create a special folder within an outlook PST file

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-outlook-2010

**Original question**

I have two problems caused by missing special folders.

I added a second email address for which Outlook created a new PST file with an *Inbox* to which emails are successfully imported.  But there is no *Deleted Items* folder.  If I attempt to delete an unwanted email it is struck out.  If  move an email to a different PST file it is copied.

I created a new PST file using Data File Management.  This PST file has no Drafts folder.  This is not important but I fail to see why I cannot have Drafts folder if I want.

Any suggestions for solving these problems, particularly the first, gratefully received.

**Update**

Thanks to Ramhound and Dave Rook for their helpful responses to my original question.  I assumed the problem of not have a *Drafts* folder in an Archive PST file and not having a *Deleted Items* folder associated with an *Inbox* were part of the same problem or I would not have mentioned the *Drafts* folder issue since I have an easy work-around.  Perhaps my question should have been: How to I load emails from an IMAP account and be able to delete the spam?

Comment: This sounds like you are connecting to an exchange and/or IMAP account.  Because you would not experience this with your typical POP3 account.

Comment: @Ramhound.  You are correct; it is an IMAP account.  I had not appreciated that this was significant.  The email address is associated with a small website hosted by One.Com.  I have no control over the account type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my version of Outlook (2010) in the Account settings for the IMAP account there is a 'More settings...' button. This shows a 'Internet E-mail Settings' dialog, with several tabs. One of those tabs is called 'Deleted Items'. There you can specify how items should be deleted, ie marked for deletion, moved to the deleted folder, and whether purging should occur when switching folders.

I've specified to move the items to a 'Deleted Items' folder and they're deleted immediately (which can make the responsiveness a little annoying) but does mean that you don't have the annoying strike-through items cluttering the list.

Comment: This sounds good.  I will try and get back.

Comment: I do not like this answer but it is correct.  Purging marked emails rather moving them to Deleted Items feels wrong but does get rid of the spam emails.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In Outlook, you only get a deleted folder for your default PST file. It shouldn't matter from which PST file you delete, it should go to your default PST deleted items.

Comment: While this information is correct.  Its not the reason for the author's problems.  You don't get the "strikeout" behavior on a  pop3 account at least not with OUtlook.

Comment: I have searched Help and the internet without success so knowing the missing _Deleted Items_ folder was not my fault is helpful.  +1 for helpful information but sorry no tick unless you can tell me how to delete spam emails.

Comment: Actually, when it is marked out it *kind of is* deleted, but remains visible! Any way, to get round this Select View | Current View | Hide Messages Marked for Deletion from the menu.

Comment: Hiding the messages marked for deletion would be an acceptable temporary solution but unless I can cut down on the robot created spam I really need to delete them.